# Can you update cookie info of user without logging them out?

Tags: php, cookies

is it possible for a cookie to update with new information without logging out the user?  I use cookies to store session auth codes and I would like that code to expire after a set time without them having to logout.  Can I simply just overwrite the cookie with the new auth code when it expires or will that cause the person to get logged out?  I never tried it, thanks.

Comment: If you're talking about sessions, you can use [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php). If it's just cookies, you can update them at anytime, you just need to make sure that your server (database?) is also updated with the new `auth codes`.

Comment: Yes thanks I plan to update the cookie and database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

update would just be resetting it :P

You would just save over the existing cookie using the same method you are already using: setCookie("username",username,1000);

Comment: Great it works perfectly :)  I have a query that checks every five minutes if session expired and if so it generates a new one in DB and with cookie